# linux perf: how to enable perf permission for specific users?

Tags: linux, user-permissions, perf, group, linux-capabilities

How to setup perf permission for specific user?
(kernel.perf_event_paranoid is not an option because it is global)

Kernel documentation is unclear or incomplete:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/perf-security.html#privileged-perf-users-groups

- Documentation mentions group need config, but does not tell how.

> 2. Assign the required capabilities to the Perf tool executable file and enable members of perf_users group with monitoring and observability privileges 6 :

- The section about creating privileged shell environment, is even worse. It does not provide any detailed instruction at all.

Comment: How are you reading the linked URL? The info appears to include quite specific shell instructions (the `#` prefix line means "run this as root", you can get into that state with the command `sudo -s`) after each step by step numbered point.

Comment: @Tinkerer I listed the two parts that the doc is lacking in the question. In "Privileged Perf users groups" section, the doc does not describe how to achieve the part I quoted, "enable members of perf_users group with monitoring and observability privileges". The section about creating privileged shell environment, does not give any detailed instruction at all.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from this web page. You create a group, `perf_users`, with this command (run as root, say via `sudo -s`):

```
# groupadd perf_users
```

Then cause a specific program file, `perf`, to be runnable only by members of that group:

```
# chgrp perf_users perf
# chmod o-rwx perf
```

Finally, it shows how to give that file capabilities:

```
# setcap "cap_perfmon,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep" perf
```

The document also includes some commands to verify the file is configured as intended: `ls -alhF` and `getcap perf`. (There is some discussion of including `cap_ipc_lock` or equivalently `38` in the capability list.)

At this point anyone, that can successfully execute this `perf` program, will observe it run with the needed capabilities.

Perhaps you are missing the command to add a user, `username`, to this newly created group? Try, `sudo usermod -G perf_users -a username`. That user will need to then log out and log in again for that added group membership to take effect.

As to the section on creating a shell wrapper, it says that a file with this content:

```
exec /usr/sbin/capsh --iab=^cap_perfmon --secbits=239 --user=$SUDO_USER -- -l
```

should be created at `/usr/local/bin/perf.shell`. You can create such content with `sudo vi /usr/local/bin/perf.shell`, or swap in whatever your favorite editor is in place of `vi`. The file needs to be made executable. To be explicit: `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/perf.shell`.

The instructions for enabling this executable script to be invoked, as `root`, via `sudo` by members of the `perf_users` group indicate the state of things when this is done. That is, you have this line is in the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
%perf_users    ALL=/usr/local/bin/perf.shell
```

You will need to `sudo vi /etc/sudoers` (or via your favorite editor) to insert that line.

Given that edit, that section ends with an example of how to enter this shell environment:

```
$ sudo perf.shell
```

From here, every binary executed in this shell context will have the specified capabilities raised.